# How do I command the discord.py bot to remove messages from a specific member?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I wanted to make a command so that I mark a member and the bot deletes all his messages.

it would be something like:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import *

bot = commands.bot(command_prefix="Mia ", case_insensitive = "True", intents=Intents.all())

@bot.command(name="clean")
async def clear(ctx, m:discord.Member):
  await m.message.delete_all()

bot.run("Token")
```

Note: this was just a hypothetical code, it doesn't work

Comment: I can't exemplify more than that, I just want to delete someone's messages that they mark in command

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through all of the guilds [channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.channels), and for each channel, iterate through its `history` ([here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history)). You can then check each message in the history to see if the author is the member you're dealing with, and if so, [delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete) the message.

Comment: It's not clear, do you have an example?  I already looked at the documentation before asking the question, but I didn't find what I was looking for